# mongo db testing error

Tags: mongodb

I came to know about Mongo db. So I installed it on ubuntu 11.04. To check whether it is installed or not I checked it in software center and it was there. So for test I made command in terminal as

```
$mongo
```

but it is something like this 
`Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79`.
so can someone tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your mongod is not running. Check the process list using "ps" and restart the mongod service if it is not started.